# Dynamic enable/disable "enableSorting" in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ui-grid

I have problem to enable disabled sorting in ui-grid in Angular 1.
I try this in grid columnsDefs:

```
{
  ...
  enableSorting: false
},
```

And I try to overwrite it when something is happening in my controller:

```
$scope.$watch("vm.verifiedCreatedRecords", function(newVal, oldVal){
  if(newVal.length > 0){ 

    vm.UpdateCreationGridOptions.columnDefs[4].enableSorting = true;
  } 
  else {
        vm.sortingCreate = false;
  }

}, true);
```

`vm.UpdateCreationGridOptions.columnDefs[4].enableSorting` become true, but the grid is not enable sorting. It remains with default status for sorting.

Also I have set for general option: "useExternalSorting: true"

Any ideas regarding how can I refresh the ui-grid? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try below refresh approaches

```
$scope.UpdateCreationGridOptions.core.queueGridRefresh();
$scope.UpdateCreationGridOptions.core.refresh();
$scope.UpdateCreationGridOptions.grid.refreshCanvas();
$scope.UpdateCreationGridOptions.grid.refreshRows();
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. I solve it with an return false in the custom sorting function.

Comment: Also I read some options are dynamic, some not. I don't find anyway in the documentation how to handle options which are set when the controller is initialized.